# Reduce the list of file types in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-excel-2016

In MS Excel 2013 or 2016, is there a way to reduce the choices in the file type selection list?
The amount of choices when choosing "Save as..." is overwhelming for some users.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer your question, but there are some registry based settings to prevent users from saving to specific file types. Unfortunately, they still show up in the dropdown. For reference, these are the fileblock policy settings. If for example, you wanted to prevent users form saving to txt files, you could set `HKCU\software\policies\microsoft\office\16.0\excel\security\fileblock!textfiles=1`. Maybe there are more settings that I don't know about. The registry settings I know about are [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25250)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know this cannot be done.

The most you can do is in menu *File > Options*, section *Save*, to set:

- The default file format used for saving new documents, using the drop-down box
  in "Save files in this format".
- The default save folder.

Comment: It seems there are no other opinions, so I have to accept this.